# RunWorkerCompleted is returning before work seems to be completed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a query to fill a combobox in a WPF application. I have a  [Xceed busy indicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) that pops up, but then closes right away before all of the items are loaded into the box. is there some way to control this. I have the disable busy indicator inside a RunWorkerCompleted method, but it seems it calls this before its done. 
Here's what I have:

```
        private void ItemSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CboCustomerList.Items.Clear();

        busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

        BackgroundWorker itemSearchWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        itemSearchWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(FillCustomers);
        itemSearchWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(itemSearchWorker_Completed);

        itemSearchWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    private void itemSearchWorker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //busyIndicator.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    }

    private void FillCustomers(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {


        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "Select * from CustTable order by NAME asc";
        string connectionString = Settings.Default.ProdConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlCmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = sql;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        connection.Open();
        reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<String> listOfString = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           listOfString.Add(reader["NAME"].ToString());
        }
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>CboCustomerList.ItemsSource = listOfString));

        connection.Close();


    }
```

Note the setting of the indicator before the call, and the turning off of the busy indicator in the itemSearchWorker_Completed function.
Shouldn't this wait until the whole function is called first?

Comment: But if I remove it from the Dispatcher, I wont be able to modify the combobox, right?

Comment: Correct - I've submitted an answer with how you can work round this

Comment: @peter-duniho is right - I've removed my answer

Comment: What is the type of object of `CboCustomerList`? Unless it's a type that populates itself asynchronously, there's nothing in the short snippet of code you've provided that would explain the behavior you describe. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: This is the complete code for the operation of the query and the filling of the combo box as well as the turning on of the busy indicator. I don't know how much more complete you want it. there is no other code being called to do this operation.

Comment: Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler is inadequate, it needs to check `e.Error` so you can report and diagnose an exception that was thrown in DoWork.  The usual reason that it seems to complete too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN you should never manipulate a UI object in the Backgroundworker DoWork event.

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in
>   your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface
>   through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

In your `FillCustomers` method, I suggest you change this line:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>CboCustomerList.ItemsSource = listOfString));
```

To this:

```
e.Result = listOfString;
```

So now the completed hander becomes:

```
private void itemSearchWorker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    CboCustomerList.ItemsSource = e.Result as List<string>; 
    //busyIndicator.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: I did this piece of code, and it is still working the same. I put a breakpoint on the completed handler and the list is filled but it seems to be taking too long to add the strings to the combobox. Is there a way to wait until all the stings in the list have been added before disabling the indicator?

Comment: That depends on the WPF ComboBox and how many items you are adding to it.  I don't know very much about WPF.  I do know about Backgroundworker and why you should never issue a Dispatcher.Invoke to manipulate UI objects in DoWork.  How many string items are in your list?

Comment: I'd suggest searching for posts regarding "WPF binding wait".